# Closure of compactly supported continuous functions in a weighed $L^2$ space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am struggling with the following question:
Define the weighed $L^2$ space:
$$L^2_{\Delta}(R)=\{f\in L^2(R): \int _Rf^2(x)(1+|x|^2)dx<+\infty\}$$
I only know that the space of compactly supported continuous functions $C_c(R)\subseteq L^2_{\Delta}(R)$ and that $C_c(R)$ is dense in $L^2(R)$, I wander what is the closure of $C_c(R)$ in $L^2_{\Delta}(R)$.

Comment: You know that the space of compactly supported $L_\Delta^2$ functions is dense in $L_\Delta^2$. However, you can clearly approximate a compactly supported $L_\Delta^2$ function by a compactly supported continuous function.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By dominated converge the space of compactly supported $L_\Delta^2(\mathbb{R})$ functions are dense in $L_\Delta^2(\mathbb{R})$ (you can approximate $f$ by the sequence $f_n= f 1_{[-n,n]}$). Using that
$$\Vert g \Vert_{L^2([-n,n])} \leq \Vert g\Vert_{L_\Delta^2([-n,n])} \leq \sqrt{n^2+1} \Vert g\Vert_{L^2([-n,n])}$$
and the fact that $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we conclude that $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L_\Delta^2(\mathbb{R})$.